# How to hide images address in content CSS3

Tags: html, image, css

in this theme with [this address](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_44910/) of the template monster live demo

i can not found image address 5 icon in header!(HOME ABOUT BLOG PROJECTS CONTACT)

what is the technology of uses?
how i can hidden address of images like this theme?

Comment: It looks like it's using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Comment: can you more explain?

Comment: In the `:before` pseudoelement of each item, a character is referenced (`.icon-home:before { content: "\f015"; }` for the home logo). A special font is used that provides nice versions of these characters. It isn't an image in the traditional sense.

Answer (score 3):

In modern webdesign, we want to achieve two things (among others):

- Minimal loading times. Reducing the number of requested resources is the main way to do that. To reduce the number of images, spriting can be used.
- Sharp icons on every resolution. This can't be easily achieved with pixel-based formats. The solution is to use vector formats like SVG or fonts.

The *Font Awesome* project helps with that. It provides a font with icons in the private use sections of unicode. It also provides CSS that you can reference, which looks like

```
...
.icon-edit:before {
  content: "\f044";
}
.icon-share:before {
  content: "\f045";
}
.icon-check:before {
  content: "\f046";
}
.icon-move:before {
  content: "\f047";
}
...
```

In your HTML, you can then do

```
<nav><ul>
  <li class="icon-home">     Home </li>
  <li class="icon-envelope"> Contact </li>
</ul></nav>
```

And the icon will be inserted in the `:before` pseudoelement. You can apply further styling to the element. The demo you linked to increases the font size, etc.

This technique gives you hundreds of pretty icons in just two files, and an easy way to include them into your markup.